# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv3d_1_input to have shape (1, 16, 16, 24) but got array with shape (24, 16, 16, 3)

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network

When I use `gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` I start having error with `video = video.transpose((3, 1, 2, 0))`

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
video = np.array(vid, dtype=np.float32)
video = video.transpose((3, 1, 2, 0))

output = model.predict(np.array([vid]))

print(output)
```

I try to make a video classification. I made a model of my classification using C3D. My C3D model use gray frames. This is why I made array of frames "video".

But when I try to make `model.predict(np.array([vid]))` I am having:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv3d_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 24, 16, 16)`

But when I use frame instead of gray I start having this issue:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv3d_1_input to have shape (1, 16, 16, 24) but got array with shape (24, 16, 16, 3)

Comment: How is `video = video.transpose((3,1,2,0))` related to `gray = ... `?

Comment: Please add a description of what you're trying to do, what you're expecting the code to do and what you're getting that's unexpected.